# Creating a global scope object

Tags: angularjs

In the following code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('UserCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    // Let's namespace the user details
    // Also great for DOM visual aids too
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.user.details = {
      "username": "Todd Motto",
      "id": "89101112"
    };

}]);
```

I have the member object user defined ($scope.user). This however is defined within the controller. Is it possible to create this as a global object so that other controllers within my app have access to the same object?

Comment: You also can use factory concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a service that is shared across all controllers:

```
app.factory('userService', function() {
    return {
        user: { 
             details: {
                 username: 'Todd Motto',
                 id: 89101112
             }
        }

    };
});
```

Then inject the service into your controller:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, userService) {
      $scope.user = userService.user;
});
```

Comment: your are using factory here. '$scope' can also be injected into function's parameter in factory. your way is also correct.
@androidDev, this is static way. to make it dynamic you have to inject scope...

Comment: Actually $rootScope can, but not the controller's scope. A service has no knowledge of controllers.

Comment: Does $scope.user = userService.user create a reference to user or a copy? If I update $scope.user in this controller, will it be automatically updated in all other controllers where userService.user is used?

Comment: Yes, it is a reference - it is the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

Use $rootScope, this will make it global as there is only one.

Here is a link to read more: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope

Don't forget to inject it into your controller before using it.

Hope this helps.